# Or-patterns in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ocaml

In OCaml, I was used to writing code which looked like:

```
let combine o1 o2 = match o1, o2 with
    | Valid, Invalid | Invalid, Valid -> Invalid
    | _ -> ...
```

I didn't find a way to write *or-patterns* in Haskell  and I really miss it. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: `Valid, Invalid | Invalid, Valid` is called an or-pattern. Your question is clear (I think) but knowing the name may help answer it.

Comment: AFAIK Haskell does not have something like this, each case has to be separate.  There are ways around this, but none of them that I can think of in 5 minutes are nearly as pretty as this OCaml example.

Comment: In fact, I have a way around in some cases. For instance, this feature is especially useful for dealing with symmetric arguments. In this case, you can match half the cases and add a last equation which perform a recursive call and reverse the order of the arguments. But it is not as nice, I agree...

Comment: I was wondering. That's fine when the pattern matching doesn't return any value but how OCaml will deal with thins like `| Valid a, Invalid | Invalid , Valid b ->` ... a or b ????

Comment: Ocaml will return an error. You can only use in the right hand size identifiers which have been defined in all patterns with the same type.

Answer (score 21):

I don't think this is possible in haskell. There are however, a few alternatives:

#### Factor out the common code with a `where` binding

This doesn't make much sense in your example, but is useful if you have more code in the body of the case expression:

```
combine o1 o2 = case (o1,o2) of
  (Valid, Invalid) -> handleInvalid
  (Invalid, Valid) -> handleInvalid
  ...
 where
  handleInvalid = ...
```

#### Use wildcard patterns

In my experience, it doesn't happen so often that you want to use *two* or patterns in one pattern match. In this case, you can handle all the "good" cases and the use a wild card pattern for the rest:

```
combine o1 o2 = case (o1,o2) of
  (Valid, Valid) -> Valid -- This is the only valid case
  _              -> Invalid -- All other cases are invalid
```

This has the disadvantage that it bypasses the exhaustiveness checker and that you cannot use wildcard patterns for other purposes.

#### Use guards and `==`

If the types you want to match against are enum-like types, you might consider making an `Eq` instance. Then you can use `==` and `||` to match multiple constructors in one guard:

```
combine o1 o2
  | o1 == Invalid && o2 == Valid || o1 == Valid && o2 == Invalid = Invalid
  | ...
```

I agree that this doesn't look as nice and it also has the disadvantage of bypassing the exhaustiveness checker and doesn't warn you if patterns overlap, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: With an `Eq` instance, you can also write ``(o1,o2)`elem`[(Invalid,Valid), (Valid,Invalid)]``. But still, equalities aren't nice – pattern-matching is preferrable.

Comment: I love how, in the “`where`” solution, you can save a lambda where an OCaml programmer would naturally have inserted one.

Answer (score 11):

You could use this quasiquoter http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OrPatterns. Your example translates to something like:

```
let combine o1 o2 = case (o1, o2) of
      [o| (Valid, Invalid) | (Invalid, Valid ) |] -> Invalid
      _ -> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/43) to add or-patterns to GHC.

Until then (in addition to the other examples), [pattern synonyms](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XPatternSynonyms) can be employed for similar means:

```
data ABC = A Int | B Int | C Bool

ab :: ABC -> Maybe Int
ab (A i) = Just i
ab (B i) = Just i
ab C{}   = Nothing

pattern AB :: Int -> ABC
pattern AB i <- (ab -> Just i)
```

If you want to match values of separate types (like `Int` and `Bool`) you can create some constrained existential type

```
data Showable where
  Showable :: Show a => a -> Showable

ac :: ABC -> Maybe Showable
ac (A i) = Just (Showable i)
ac (C b) = Just (Showable b)
ac B{}   = Nothing

pattern AC :: () => Show a => a -> ABC
pattern AC showable <- (ac -> Just (Showable showable))

showAC :: ABC -> String
showAC (AC showable) = "A or C: " ++ show showable
showAC (B i)         = "B: "      ++ show i
```