# Haskell: Is there a better way to write case statements with the same RHS?

Tags: haskell, case

Example:

```
data A =
  A B D
  | Aa B C
  | Ag B X X
  | Ae B R Q
  | Ax X

getB a = case a of 
    (A b _)         -> b
    (Aa b _)        -> b
    (Ag b _ _)      -> b
    (Ae b _ _)      -> b
    (Ax _)          -> somethingElse
```

In Haskell, given a data type where many of the constructors have the same argument type, is there a better way to return this argument. Or is there a better way to write the `case` statement shown above to have less repetition?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700762/or-patterns-in-haskell

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27960784/783743

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use record syntax to hack get around this:

```
data A =
  A {fieldB :: B, fieldC :: C} |
  Aa {fieldB :: B, fieldX1 :: X, fieldX2 :: X} |
  Ag {fieldB :: B, fieldR :: R, fieldQ :: Q} |
  Ax {fieldX :: X}

getB a = case a of
  Ax -> somethingElse
  _  -> fieldB a
```

The key thing is to give *the same name* to all the fields of type `B`.

Comment: This looks just like David Young's answer, except without adding the `lens` layer.

Comment: My point being that you don't need Template Haskell plus a large, complex library. It's just record syntax.

Comment: Yes, that's a point. I guess I just think it would make sense to mention the relationship between the two answers, as they're based on the same concept.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since this is the actual method I'm using to deal with this issue, but there were a lot of good answers and I have learned a lot. So thanks for all the answers guys :)

Answer (score 4):

A feature called "or patterns", available in ML, helps a lot with this. Such a feature was [requested](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3919) for GHC five years ago, but no one appears to have taken on the task of specifying the details and actually implementing it. However, there is a [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OrPatterns) offering a way to do something like this with Template Haskell, as explained in [Or-patterns in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700762/or-patterns-in-haskell/24741660#24741660)

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching at the function level will help with readability but since these are all differents constructors there is no way to pattern match more than one of them at a time (that I know of).

```
getB (A b _)    = b
getB (Aa b _)   = b
getB (Ag b _ _) = b
getB (Ae b _ _) = b
getB (Ax _)     = somethingElse
```

Comment: This.  There is no fundamental correlation between the `b` in each of these constructors; they're just all coincidentally labeled the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`Prism`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html) and the [`(^?)` operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:-94--63-) from the [`lens` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:-94--63-) to make this a little easier:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

-- ...

data A =
  A { _b :: B, _d :: D }
  | Aa { _b :: B, _c :: C }
  | Ag { _b :: B, _x1 :: X, _x2 :: X }
  | Ae { _b :: B, _r :: R, _q :: Q }
  | Ax { _x1 :: X }

makeLenses ''A

getB :: A -> B
getB a = case a ^? b of
  Just theB -> theB
  Nothing   -> somethingElse
```

The call to the Template Haskell function `makeLenses` takes care of all the boilerplate.

`lens` might be a bit of a heavy dependency if you're only using it for this, but it's something to consider (especially if you are already using `lens`/considering using `lens`).

Comment: Isn't  it generally considered poor form to name fields of non-record types? Is it possible to make just the total things?

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not sure what you mean by a "non-record type", but if those fields are just accessed through the `lens` functions, everything should stay nice and total. You could enforce this by not exporting the underscored names.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` has a Data instance, you can write

```
import Data.Data
mgetB :: A -> Maybe B
mgetB = gmapQi 0 cast
```

and then define getB in terms of that function

Answer (score 1):

At some point you have to say how your `B`s are contained inside `A` so you many as well do it once and for all in a general way.

```
bOrX a = case a of
    (A b _)         -> B' b
    (Aa b _)        -> B' b
    (Ag b _ _)      -> B' b
    (Ae b _ _)      -> B' b
    (Ax x)          -> X' x
```

Subsequently you can match all `B`s at once with very little code.

```
getB a = case bOrX a of
  B' b -> b
  X' _ -> somethingElse

anotherFunctionWithBandX a = case bOrX a of
  B' b -> f b
  X' x -> g x
```